# Are downloaded data automatically licensed?

Tags: copyright, apache-2.0, license

If a purely Apache v2 licensed software automatically downloads data files from its copyright holder's website without asking the user, does that automatically grant Apache v2 license to the downloaded files? Does the user have permission to use the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be a resounding "no".

The licensing of any data file protected by copyright is completely up to the copyright's author, and he or she may bot may not choose to license these files under some permissive license. The fact that the tool used to download it was licensed under some particular license is completely inconsequential.

Comment: Moreover, distributing copies of software that makes other people's computers do illegal things [may well itself be illegal](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2018/07/27/ransomware_coinvault_community_service/).  Think very carefully before you write and distribute this software.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have added that the downloaded data files are also copyrighted under the same owner of the software.